# htaccess require local breaks background images

Tags: css, .htaccess

I have my image folder protected from browsing using the following line in my .htaccess file:

```
require local
```

This provides the security I require, but prevents CSS background images from displaying.

```
style="background: url(../data/profile_img/profile_10.jpg?x=1444352490)"
```

Accessing the file using an img tag works, but css does not.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself.
Turns out my .htaccess was not being honoured at all.

The solution was to remove 
+FollowSymLinks from the apache config file, in the directory area

```
<Directory "/var/www">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```